# Photon Voice AudioSource 3D audio not following player in Unity Y axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon, unity-webgl

We have a problem with audiosource 3D, when player moves in Unity Y axis, the audiosource component does not follow the player position. This results that the volume of other players is very, very low when we are above the Y-origin point (as if the Audiosource is very far, but it should be following the player).

The other players are being synced through their transform, and the audiosource is a child of the player. So if the player is being transformed, the audiosource should follow, and is not behaving as expected, since the audiosource is fixed to another position in the scene.
Important to notice that everything works well when in unity editor, but the problem emerges when building to WEBGL.

Using Latest Photon Voice version 2.55, UNITY 2022.3.15F1 LTS and Photon Fusion.

Comment: Impossible to say what might be wrong with code we cannot see. Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.